# JSON.value gives undefined, despite JSON.stringify showing value

Tags: javascript, aws-serverless

In my Serverless application I recieve a request with data like this

```
{
  "captcha": "asdf"
}
```

I have been unable to extract this data from the body of the request. Here's what my code looks like:

```
module.exports.contact = (event, context, callback) => {
    var body = querystring.parse(event.body);
    var str  = JSON.stringify(body);
    var obj  = JSON.parse(str); // I know this is horribly inefficient, just testing
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty('captcha'))
    {
        callback(null, {statusCode: 400, body: "No Captcha" + JSON.stringify(obj) + obj.captcha});
        return;
    }
```

My Serverless endpoint sends the following response body:-

```
No Captcha{"{\n\"captcha\": \"asdf\"\n}":""}undefined
```

I think that because I can stringify body, parse it into obj, and stringify it again, and get valid JSON, I should be able to get the obj property captcha - But I can't..?

Comment: Seems like you could use a simple RegExp to grab that Json out of the body  and avoid some of these weird parsing issues.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use `body-parser` if you don't want to parse the stream of data to a json, but you can do it by yourself using multipart body

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved this by removing the querystring function and doing var obj = JSON.parse(event.body);

Seems like I confused myself into believing that event.body needs to be specially parsed when in fact it is just the body, like the name suggests